# Jquery ajax post, can't get post data

Tags: jquery, ajax

so I am trying to make a ajax post so I made a simple post:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'example1.php',
  data: ({Imgname:"13"}),
  success: function(data) {
    //alert(data);
  }
 });
 });

 </script>
 <?php 
 $temp = $_GET['Imgname'];
 echo $temp;
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But it I don't get anything, what am I doing wrong? please help.

Comment: try with $_POST['Imgname']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should must work for your case:
Here is your HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'example1.php',
                    data: {Imgname: "13"},
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

INSIDE your example1.php File you have to check with:

```
<?php 
        $temp = $_POST['Imgname'];
        echo $temp; exit; 
?>
```

Your mistake was, you was sending the POST request and you was trying to get data in $_GET variable. Another mistake with your data posted as well. Try my code now.

Answer (score 1):

- `data: ({Imgname:"13"}),` should be `data: {Imgname:"13"},`
- The default `type` of `ajax` is `get` ..But while you use `type: "POST",` use `$_POST['Imgname'];` instead of `$_GET['Imgname'];`
- If `console.log(data);` after changes still returns an error so check the path of `url: 'example1.php',`
- If the `ajax` and the `php` code in the same file so use `url: '/',` and put the php code on top of the html code and in php after echo `return false;`

Comment: ok I have done what you told me to do, the console now shows the entire page code, but nothig is being echoed

Comment: @johnsnow I updated my answer with another check point . But for me it will better to use separated files one for js and another for php